# Overlapping address to Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript

I'm trying to find an address of an error in OpenAPI, does anyone have an elegant solution to solve the issue of overlapping arrays where the previous path includes some of the current path.

```js
const inputPaths = [
    ["components", "schemas", "EmployeeDto"],
    ["components", "schemas", "EmployeeDto", "properties", "items"],
    ["properties", "items", "items"],
];

const flattenPaths = (paths: string[][]) => {
    // TODO: Flatten Paths
};

it("should flatten to fixed address", () => {
    expect(flattenPaths(inputPaths)).toEqual(["components", "schemas", "EmployeeDto", "properties", "items", "items"]);
});
```

Edit: A Working solution, but anything nicer would be grand.

```js
import _, { last, slice } from "lodash";

const inputPaths = [
    ["components", "schemas", "EmployeeDto"],
    ["components", "schemas", "EmployeeDto", "properties", "items"],
    ["properties", "items", "items"],
];

const flattenPaths = (paths: string[][]) => {
    let address = paths[0].join(".");

    _(paths)
        .slice(1, paths.length)
        .forEach((pathParts) => {
            const candidates = pathParts.map((item, idx, all) => slice(all, 0, idx + 1).join("."));

            const greediestMatch = _(candidates)
                .filter((it) => address.includes(it))
                .last();

            // @ts-ignore
            address = address + last(candidates).replace(greediestMatch, "");
        });

    return address.split(".");
};

it("should flatten", () => {
    expect(flattenPaths(inputPaths)).toEqual(["components", "schemas", "EmployeeDto", "properties", "items", "items"]);
});
```

Comment: Why is "items" included twice in the expected array? Otherwise, you could make a set to filter out duplicate values: `const flattenPaths = (paths) => {
  return [...new Set([...paths.flat()])];
};`

Comment: I don't know that this is quite well-defined enough for an answer. What should `[["a","b"],["a"]]` flatten to? What should `[["a"],["a"]]` flatten to?  You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/Ndj60W), which results in `["a", "b", "a"]` and `["a"]` respectively, but I have no idea if that's what you're looking for.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Any value is valid unfortunately. I don't think it should happen but the only rule is a part of the address overlaps the previous.

Comment: Which comment are you replying to?  Could you please tell me whether [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/Ndj60W) does what you want?

Comment: @jcalz nice  works well

Comment: Okay, I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to write `flattenPaths` like this:

```
const flattenPaths = (paths: string[][]): string[] => {
  return paths.reduce((acc, cur): string[] => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= acc.length; i++) {
      if (acc.slice(i).every((v, j) => cur[j] === v)) {
        return [...acc.slice(0, i), ...cur];
      }
    }
    throw new Error("unreachable");
  }, [])
};
```

The idea is that you are accumulating a flattened path `acc` by iterating over each input path `cur` via [the `Array.prototype.reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).  The new path `cur` might overlap with the end part of the accumulated path `acc`, so you want to eliminate that overlap before attaching the current path.  So how do you find the overlap?

The idea would be to walk through the `acc` array from index `0` up to its length, and for each index, see if the beginning of `cur` matches the full `acc` array starting from that index.  Either this will happen somewhere before you reach the end of the `acc` array (e.g., if `acc` is `["a","b","c"]` and `cur` is `["b","c","d"]`, then you will find overlap when you reach index `1`), or it will happen when you reach the end of the array (e.g., if `acc` is `["a", "b", "c"]` and `cur` is `["d", "e", "f"]`, then you will find overlap when you reach index `3`, that is, the zero elements starting with index 3 of `acc` matches the zero elements at the beginning of `cur`).  Either way you will find the overlap before leaving the loop. The compiler doesn't see that, though, so I've thrown an error there.

Equivalently, you could exit the loop before reaching the length of `acc` and just concatenate the two lists if you reach that:

```
const flattenPaths = (paths: string[][]): string[] => {
  return paths.reduce((acc, cur): string[] => {
    for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) { // <-- strictly less than
      if (acc.slice(i).every((v, j) => cur[j] === v)) {
        return [...acc.slice(0, i), ...cur];
      }
    }
    return [...acc, ...cur] // <-- concatenate
  }, [])
};
```

Either way, it works for your example input:

```
console.log(flattenPaths([
  ["components", "schemas", "EmployeeDto"],
  ["components", "schemas", "EmployeeDto", "properties", "items"],
  ["properties", "items", "items"],
]));
// ["components", "schemas", "EmployeeDto", "properties", "items", "items"]
```

Note that this may or may not do what you want for edge cases.  For example:

```
console.log(flattenPaths([["a", "b"], ["a"]]))
// ["a", "b", "a"]
```

Here the algorithm does not expect that you could possibly *shorten* the accumulated path, so it does not match the second `"a"` to the first `"a"`.  Instead it decides that there's a zero-length overlap and puts the second `"a"` at the end.  As another example:

```
console.log(flattenPaths([["a"], ["a"]]))
// ["a"]
```

Here the algorithm *does* expect that you might *not lengthen* the accumulated path, so it does match the second `"a"` to the first `"a"`.  There's a length-one overlap and so the accumulated path is just `"a"`.

These behaviors seem reasonable to me, but if they are not desirable, then the algorithm would need to change.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgGwIZSgUzABRQCwjAXhgAoAHXCALhmgCcBLMAcwG0BddgSmrsdbcIA+GAG8AUDBi00UAK60wMclDwA6aQBNZwNMWJJgwADQxg87jSgNm7IaImT4IWiQQyY9QjAAMAbg8wADxEBsCqbswq-vQA1DGc9o6O9HAkoaoQCPQ6xPScqmgAbmi0AJ56hSYAVgkEwma0LFUCBK0whZwJ4klJ0nIKMCyqw+mZ2breJnkmw6oNbL4OSQC+SzCrSSq0IADuMGBoewCitNu0xABEsmDSBjhIAEZuF5yLkssmXGLLi2KgkLBECh0FgKABBBAQEBeMgUHhWPjsLjw6z8OzdKQyeSKZRqTTaXT6QwmBoWXg2FrCDGSODOVzuTxEPwBQIwdIRJhRDxxLprSQpNKGDJZHJ5ArFMoVaq1eryJotNodXk9Rx9bGDWajEUTKacGbDeZvHobRwmyRqgZDEbEmCzeYOD6DNicb6-P7gKFucIgJjEIGoDDYFQQYgsBwsC6gAC2pHAGCgEAuJguEGAODQUaQieTRxjCBApTQaAAIlAQBc2EZw5GQDG42AE0mYCm0xms02LrnSPnCyWyx3SNtSCUoPQ0Nnm-R0FHE5Xq4OQMPaKPxx2pxmJxd1zOK1Xna8xAB6Q+DGt1g4Nzep9OZzddntF0vl5MLpcrzfbj-T2cwd2QEBevmvr+iCQZ4KGEZIB2Dy7qeUFsPuR4npB0EdvBv7-J6aDesByABqCwYQRc8GfMRFaIcecEVr+YhAA)